# Retrieving values from outterclass in order to display the JProgressBar accordingly

Tags: java, user-interface

I work on a project which I have one class for the gui and another one for my calculations.

I would like to retrieve some values like the incrementation (i) of the main for loop of class calculations in order to update the JProgressBar in GUI class accordingly.

I have tried to do that by using SwingWorker but I am a little bit lost.

Moreover I cannot run execute method inside a main, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Anestis

Comment: You may pass the progressbar object to the class where the calculation loop is running, then you can increment it in required loops.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to to attach a property change listener to the SwingWorker thread from within the class containing the JProgressBar as below:

```
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) {
                bar.setValue(Integer.parseInt(arg0.getNewValue().toString());
            }
        }
});
```

Then, when then the value of the worker thread reaches a certain interval, you would fire off a PropertyChangeEvent to update the progress bar.

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
     public Void doInBackground() {
         for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
             // Do something
             firePropertyChange("progress", i-1, i);
         }

         return null;
     }

     public void done() {
        try {
            get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```